# Equivalent of !$A.util.isEmpty() in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I have been using `!$A.util.isEmpty(var)` to check if value in empty/null/undefined in aura but this is not supported in LWC. What will be equivalent of this expression in LWC.

I don't want to write like `if(this.var!==null && this.var!==undefined && this.var!=='')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a great question. Actually, it's more of a Javascript question than a LWC related question.

Quite simply because the answer is not related to LWC but to pure Javascript.

You just need to use the below code:

```
if(var){
}
```

In fact, Javascript will check if the var value is not undefined, not null and not an empty string.

**EDIT**

If we had to compare Aura to LWC in general, I would say that LWC is a real Javascript framework, a modern framework. This often involves Javascript takes a much more important place than the view, unlike Aura. But also that it is possible to use all the power of today's Javascript. And this is awesome!

Comment: Thanks @Martin! This is simple and elegant.

Comment: Glad I could help @devforce !

Comment: This doesn't help with lockerservice on. `if(var){}` is always true if var contains: `<target>: []
​length: 0
​<prototype>: []
<handler>: {…}`.... but it's still empty